# Need 10 seconds to execute "Hello World"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sublimetext

Lately, I've been trying to configure my C and C++ in VSCode. After installation, I ran my code and it needs 10 seconds on both VSCode and Sublime Text to run a "Hello World" program. Both IDE work well in python files.

The code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Sublime text output:

> Hello World[Finished in 10.9s]

I tried to change from MSYS2 to MINGW. I deleted the MSYS2 files and replaced them with MINGW but nothing happened.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with running code in VSCode, but since C++ is a compiled language I suspect the 10s is from compiling the code before running it. 10s doesn't seem unreasonable for that sort of program. Python is an interpreted language so no compilation step is needed before running the code.

Comment: if you have an antivirus, add the folder you are using to the exclusion list.

Comment: @jla I'm using a compiler because everyone does. Is it really necessary? And how long does your IDE need to execute a C program?

Comment: *'I tried to change from MSYS2 to MINGW.'* Making random changes to try and fix a problem you do not understand is a very bad idea, and often just leads to more trouble.

Comment: It could also be that you are running it though the debugger, like gdb, and that it needs time to download debugging libraries.

Comment: *"I tried to change from MSYS2 to MINGW"* Note that the [VSCode install guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) *specifically* tells you to use MSYS2 and not some ancient MinGW download.

Comment: Try building and debugging using a command line window and not using an IDE?  Also, build the program in Release Mode and execute from a command line window. Are any of these around 10s?